# What's Causing High CPU Use On GMail?

Tags: firefox, cpu-usage, gmail, opera

I've seen this on Opera, Vivaldi and Firefox. When a open a gmail page the cpu goes up and keeps there around 2min/3min. If I open my two email pages then it goes crazy... some time ago I left as fixed tab on opera both gmail pages and the opening of the browser was a pain! I'm using laptop, that's because I'm worried/curious about this, If someone has any ideia...

Comment: gmail need huge resource, just use basic HTML gmail if want low resource

Comment: This happens in Linux? Which Firefox version?

Comment: If you have a low-powered HW, I guess it could happen, but it's in any case no question for us to solve. Voting to close.

Comment: I won't ask for any details as for the lack of it, just because it does not meet our community I believe.

Comment: Firefox 80.0b1. Indeed, there is nothing to solve.